# Inconsistent email notifications from ZoHo task lists

Tags: zoho

My office has been using Zoho to manage a few ongoing projects.  The whole purpose is for everyone involved to get email alerts and notifications when a task is created and be able to add notes and status updates.  The trouble is most of the time we do not get any emails from some of the tasklists.  There doesn't seem to be any consistent pattern.  Sometimes I get an email in my box as soon as I enter a task.  Other times it never comes. We have called Zoho customer service twice, and they have not been able to help.

Answer (score 1):

In Zoho Projects users will be notified only if they are connected to that activity.

For example, if you create a Task, you alone will get notified about that and if that same Tasks gets updated by any other user, you will get notified about it because you are the creator of the Task. If some other user creates a Task and starts working on it, you will not get reminded about the same as you aren't apart of that Task.

You can control your Notifications by accessing:

> Settings → Email Notification → Configure Notifications